# Android set Roboto font with bold, italic, regular,... (something like custom font family)

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, font-family

I know ho to set custom font programmatically inside Android app.
Is there any way to load typeface for custom font (assets) and Android framework will use proper file based on bold, italic and so on?

For example now I'm trying to set Roboto font to some `TextView`

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

It works ok. But since I set `TextView` inside xml layout to bold , text is not bolded

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/my_text"
    android:textColor="@color/my_foreground"
    android:textSize="24dp" />
```

How to load typeface from assets properly that this will work?

```
textView.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Inside my assets dir there is only one "font family"

```
Roboto-Black.ttf
Roboto-BlackItalic.ttf
Roboto-Bold.ttf
Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf
Roboto-BoldCondensedItalic.ttf
Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf
Roboto-Condensed.ttf
Roboto-CondensedItalic.ttf
Roboto-Italic.ttf
Roboto-Light.ttf
Roboto-LightItalic.ttf
Roboto-Medium.ttf
Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf
Roboto-Regular.ttf
Roboto-Thin.ttf
Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf
```

How to load all that fonts inside one typeface/family?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's a good idea to post a link, but anyway...
Here is my blog post on this topic, it has a class that solves this problem fully.
http://anton.averin.pro/2012/09/12/how-to-use-android-roboto-font-in-honeycomb-and-earlier-versions/

Comment: Looks good, but formatting is broken. Why not paste the same class here?

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Yes, sorry, the website is down for years already.
You can now use android databinding to use any kind of font

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to treat different typeface variants of a single font as one family, but typefaces tend to have large file sizes so you probably wouldn't want to import all those typefaces into your app anyway. Instead, you could use just the Medium font and then set bold and italic attributes for that.

For example, if you have android:textStyle="bold" set in your XML layout, you can do this in your code to keep the bold style:

```
Typeface currentTypeFace = textView.getTypeface();
if (currentTypeFace != null && currentTypeFace.getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD) {
    textView.setTypeface(tf, Typeface.BOLD);
} else {
    textView.setTypeface(tf);
}
```